# Making GWT and Dart work together? What are the benefits?

Tags: java, gwt, dart

I recently found out about Dart and GWT integration, (BTW, I'm a GWT developer) although I haven't had the time to view the video, I got interested in learning how to test it out with my GWT application; right now I'm looking on how to make Dart work on my GWT client side code first.

**Questions:**

- When doing Dart + GWT what are the parts of the application that can be put to work together?
- On the client side GWT and Dart can work together for both are compiled to Javascript? And regarding this part, does the Dart Browser-side access to Restful interfaces any better in terms of code maintenance?
- Is it possible that Dart server side (bytecodes) to Run within the JVM? Or that would be very slow?

Comment: Thanks for the question, but please note. This is a good format for programmers.stackexchange.com. This question, due to its subjective nature, is at a high risk of being closed.

Comment: Right, so I rephrased my question already.

Comment: @seth-ladd oops your one of those who voted this question to be closed. I already reconstructed my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This video and blog post](http://news.dartlang.org/2013/02/dart-with-google-web-toolkit.html) (which I'm guessing is the one you mention in your question) from Shannon Behrens discusses using GWT and Dart.

1. The following topics are covered in the video, which answers the first point in your questions.

   - Using GWT and Dart to manage different parts of the same page
   - Using Dart to retrieve JSON from a Java servlet
   - Using window.postMessage and JSNI to pass messages between GWT and Dart
   - Using JavaScript, JSNI, and Dart's js package for synchronous interoperability between GWT and Dart
   - Using CustomEvent objects and Elemental to pass messages between GWT and Dart
2. With regards to the second question, Dart uses the same underlying AJAX APIS as JavaScript, for example, JavaScripts `XMLHttpRequest` is `HttpRequest` in Dart.  Using this, you can GET / POST etc... from restful APIs.
3. The third question "Is it possible that Dart server side (bytecodes) to Run within the JVM":  Dart doesn't have bytecode.  Dart on the server-side is like node.js (server-side javascript), python, ruby etc... rather than being compiled into a form of bytecode like Java.  There was an early experiment to take Dart code and make it run on the JVM, but that was more an early proof of concept rather than anything for real use (ref: https://code.google.com/p/jdart/ )

Answer (score 1):

1. GWT cannot be supplanted by Dart in years to come . Dart is still in MileStone 4. Google approach to web w.r.t GWT, DART, Closure etc is summarized [here](http://www.igvita.com/2012/01/05/google-web-toolkit-gwt-closure-nacl-dart-js/).
2. I do not see any benefits of Dart when compared to GWT w.r.t to JSON . It can be argued but never settled in either side.
3. Dart might have the GAE support in already - http://news.dartlang.org/2013/03/irrduino-sprinkler-system-built-using.html

**NOTE:**
I have written only few hello world programs in Dart. As of today , Dart is in Milestone 4 release

1. Dart only runs in Customized Chrome ( Dartium Browser). Firefox, IE might never support it natively and currently hostile to it!!!! Dart compiles to Javascript (Dart2JS compiler) in the same way GWT compiles java to javascript. This allows it to provide a compatibility with IE, Firefox.
2. Unless Dart gets supported by FireFox or turns out 10x or 100x performance w.r.t javascript it is not likely to get traction with other browsers. It currently is around 2x or 3x performance w.r.t javascript when run natively in dartium browser.

Comment: When you say dart only runs on Dartium, did you mean the pure Dart and not the Dart-to-Javascript right?

Comment: Dart runs on all modern browsers as JavaScript output.  JavaScript output from Darts dart2js tool is already beating hand-written JavaScript in some benchmarks: http://www.dartlang.org/performance/

Comment: I mention that in 1 point under Note.

Comment: One can argue that the "advantage" of `Dart` over `GWT` is more on the language level than on the performance level. 
`Java` as a language is quite verbose especially when you develop for the web (might change with Java 8). 
Dart has a lot of really nice language features (Futures, functional programming, etc) that significantly increases coding productivity when writing web-apps. However in contrast to plain `Javascript` `Dart` has also brings great tooling support and type checks help developing complex web-apps. BWT. I am a GWT developer but I really like Dart's approach.

Comment: Yes. Indeed it can bring in some much needed nifty tooling and productivity features but it can no way get Micro$oft, FireFox , Apple etc to switch over easily. The only way you can get management buy in for Dart as toolset in your webapp is when you can show "Performance" of 10x or 100x over javascript!!!!